# Как установить доступ к `jsp` странице только по ссылке?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Здравствуйте, у меня возникли проблемы и я не смог найти решение.

Мне надо установить доступ к странице регистрации только для тех пользователей, которые получили ссылку от админа. Я представляю это так - админ отправляет ссылку и только один пользователь может зайти по ней, после ссыль не активна.

Я понимаю что админ должен сгенерировать ссылку, но не знаю как. И я не знаю как установить доступ по этой ссылке. Не нашел информацию как это сделать.

**Код:**

```
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/index").hasAnyRole(USER, ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole(ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/addUser").hasRole(ADMIN)
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/login")
                .and()
                    .rememberMe()
                    .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
                    .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
                    .tokenValiditySeconds(900);
    }
```

**Панель админа с регистрацией нового пользователя:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>


<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Users List</title>
    <link href="<c:url value='/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css' />" rel="stylesheet"></link>

</head>

<body>
<div class="generic-container">
    <%--<%@include file="authheader.jsp" %>--%>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <!-- Default panel contents -->
        <div class="panel-heading"><span class="lead">User Administration</span></div>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
                    <th width="100"></th>
                </sec:authorize>
                <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
                    <th width="100"></th>
                </sec:authorize>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
                <tr>
                    <td>${user.username}</td>
                    <td>${user.firstname}</td>
                    <td>${user.lastname}</td>
                    <td>${user.email}</td>
                    <td>${user.roles}</td>
                    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
                        <td><a href="<c:url value='/edit-user-${user.username}' />" class="btn btn-success custom-width">edit</a></td>
                    </sec:authorize>
                    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
                        <td><a href="<c:url value='/delete-user-${user.username}' />" class="btn btn-danger custom-width">delete</a></td>
                    </sec:authorize>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
        <div class="well">
            <a href="<c:url value='/addUser' />">Add New User</a>
        </div>
    </sec:authorize>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Если нужен еще код, выложу.

Comment: Это сайт русскоязычного сообщества, либо задавайте вопрос на русском языке, либо задайте его на stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов решения много, на первый взгляд я бы добавил генератор строк и такую реализацию:

- админ генерирует строку определенной или произвольной длины
- строка сохраняется на сервере
- админ передает ссылку со строкой в `url` например `https://example.com/lolgin/tRdskjb33_dksvlg_3444_dskdl`
- пользователь переходит по ссылке, строка из урла проверяется на сервере, есть ли такая, если есть - присваивается значение, что переход осуществлен
- строкой воспользовались, в следующий раз проверка не пустит пользователя на сайт

А вообще читайте о `cookies` и как с их помощью можно ограничить пользовательский контент.

Comment: А как сгенерировать эту строку? Куда ее передавать? Вообщем вопросов много)

Comment: Гуглите "генератор строк", "обмен данными по http" для Вашего языка, фреймворка и т.д.